# Paginating a parent in SQL Server on a parent/child query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

(SQL Server 2012 - Web Edition)

I have a parent/child (one to many) relationship in a query like so:

```
SELECT a.a, a.b, b.c
FROM tablea INNER JOIN 
tableb ON b.pk = a.fk
```

I have a huge pagination query that encompasses this using the standard (psuedo-code):

```
WITH C as (SELECT top(@perpage*@pagenum) rowID = row_number() OVER (somefield)),
 SELECT c.* FROM C (query) WHERE DT_RowId > (@pagenum-1)*@perpage
```

The question I have is in this scenario is it possible to paginate off the parent table (a), instead of the entire query?  Can I modify my pagination query (not the sql that pulls the query itself) so that when I ask for 10 rows, it gives me 10 rows from the parent, with 'x' number of children attached?

I know I'm not giving the bigger picture here, but the bigger picture is ugly.  If need be, we can go there, but it's out there.  Here's a small taste of where we're going with this:

```
    IF UPPER(LEFT(@rSQL, 6)) = 'SELECT'
        BEGIN
            SET @rSQL = 'SELECT * FROM (' + @rSQL + ')' + ' as rTBL';
            SET @rSQL = RIGHT(@rSQL, LEN(@rSQL)-7);
            IF (LEN(LTRIM(@search)) > 0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @rPaging = 
                        'IF (@schemaonly=1) SET FMTONLY ON; 
                        SELECT @ttlrows = COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT ' + @rSQL + @rWhere + ') AS TBL; 
                        WITH C as (select top(@perpage*@pagenum) DT_RowId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (' + @rOrder + '), ';
                    SET @rPaging = @rPaging + @rSQL + @rWhere + ')  
                        SELECT C.*' + @rcols + ', (@perpage-1) * @pagenum as pagenum, @ttlrows as ct, CEILING(@ttlrows / CAST(@perpage AS FLOAT)) as pages 
                        FROM C '+ @query + ' WHERE DT_RowId > (@pagenum-1) * @perpage ';
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN

                    SET @rPaging = 
                        'IF (@schemaonly=1) SET FMTONLY ON; 
                        SELECT @ttlrows = COUNT(*) FROM (' + @oSQL + ') AS SUBQUERY; 
                        WITH C as (select top(@perpage*@pagenum) DT_RowId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (' + @rOrder + '), ';
                    SET @rPaging = @rPaging + @rSQL + ')  
                        SELECT C.*' + @rcols + ',(@perpage-1) * @pagenum as pagenum, @ttlrows as ct, CEILING(@ttlrows / CAST(@perpage AS FLOAT)) as pages 
                        FROM C '+ @query + ' WHERE DT_RowId > (@pagenum-1) * @perpage ';
                END
            PRINT @rPaging;
            EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @rPaging, @parms, @ttlrows out, @schemaonly, @perpage, @pagenum, @fksiteID, @filter1, @filter2, @filter3, @filter4, @intfilter1, @intfilter2, @intfilter3, @intfilter4, @datefilter1, @datefilter2, @search;
            SET FMTONLY OFF;
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @rSQL = LTRIM(REPLACE(UPPER(@rSQL), 'EXEC',''));
            EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @rSQL, @parms, @ttlrows out, @schemaonly, @perpage, @pagenum, @fksiteID, @filter1, @filter2, @filter3, @filter4, @intfilter1, @intfilter2, @intfilter3, @intfilter4, @datefilter1, @datefilter2;
        END
```

Comment: could you please tell sql server version ?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 (web edition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the pagination in a CTE that only gets the parent rows, and then join the child rows in a subsequent CTE or in the main query.

Due to the dynamic way you are using this, this might have to involve building your pagination query from the same building blocks you use to build `@query`.   Without seeing the code that builds `@query` I can't be much more specific than that.

Comment: The query itself is actually driven by a table.   So the query is pre-built, with built in pre-set (predictable) parameters.

Comment: It would require me to rethink how I handle queries, but that may be the only way?

Comment: Yes you may have to build the pagination part of the query with logic from the same table that builds the query.

Comment: If you go the CTE route, then I'd recommend to use TOP(@rows_required) ... ORDER BY instead of ROW_NUMBER() ... WHERE ROW_NUMBER() < = @rows_required. (code snippet extremely simplified :-) )

Comment: And keep in mind that SQL Server 2012 added the `OFFSET..FETCH` keywords to the `ORDER BY` clause, specifically for doing Pagination.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, and after looking into it, requires me to rethink some things, but it was not as daunting as I thought.  And offset and fetch is so much easier... I will look into that too.

Answer (score 3):

You could add

```
,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY table_a.primary_key)
```

This would indirectly provide the same result as

```
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_a.primary_key)
```

but the former would be on the final result set instead going back to table a for the latter code snippet.

But please be aware of the disadvantage: any additional ranking function will force an additional  sort operation on the result set! This might significantly influence the query performance. If this is the case in your scenario, I'd recommend to follow Tab Allemans solution and use a cte.